# Numerical values of open arguments in linux

Tags: linux, operating-system

I am looking at the linux manual for the `open` function [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) but I am not able to find the integer values to the various flags such
as `O_WRONLY, O_CREAT, O_RDONLY`. Is there a way to find this information?

Comment: Why do you need to know this instead of just using the macros?

Comment: When you import the headers, you can use `printf("O_WRONLY is defined as %d\n", O_WRONLY);` to show the numerical value. Alternatively, open the headers and follow the includes to the definition. Knowing the numerical value is not necessary to use this function in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I found the definitions:

```
$ find /usr/include -type f -name '*.h' -exec grep -E '^#define.*O_(WRONLY|RDONLY|RDWR)' {} +
/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h:#define O_RDONLY   00000000
/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h:#define O_WRONLY   00000001
/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h:#define O_RDWR     00000002
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl-linux.h:#define O_RDONLY        00
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl-linux.h:#define O_WRONLY        01
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl-linux.h:#define O_RDWR          02
```